# Apache Aurora GPU Resources

Tags: mesos, apache-aurora

I am checking out Apache Aurora with the scope of running scientific workflows (assuming a set of python scripts in a particular sequence). I've successfully managed to run a few of these aurora Jobs, and it looks great for my particular use-case.

I was wondering if there is a way to specify that a particular task (or job, in general) requires a number of GPU resources from my Apache Mesos cluster Of course Mesos needs to be aware of the GPU resources first, and it seems this is possible by defining these GPU resources as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872558/does-apache-mesos-recognize-gpu-cores).

So the question is whether there is a way to communicate with Mesos via Aurora to accept offers with GPU resources available. As far as I can tell, the Resource object in Aurora is limited to CPU/Ram/Disk resources. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Apache Aurora, but Mesosphere Marathon (a framework similar to Aurora in functionality) is limited to cpu, mem, and disk resources as well.

If you would like to use custom resources, you would probably need to write your own framework. Depending on your needs it may not be that difficult. For inspiration, check the [RENDLER](https://github.com/mesosphere/RENDLER) framework.

As mentioned in the thread you are referencing to, Mesos do not provide isolation for GPU (actually, for any custom) resources. Keep this is in mind when doing resource math.

Comment: I figured as much. It seems some work is being done at Mesos level to integrate other resources such as GPUs and FPGAs: [link(]https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2262)

That means frameworks could eventually integrate this - but I doubt this will be in time for my project :(

Comment: Yep, you may want to opt for writing your own framework. Still you can create a ticket in both Marathon and Aurora.

Answer (score 0):

When checking the [Aurora tutorial](http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration-tutorial/) I assume you can just specify this ressource as part of you job description:
    `resources = Resources(cpu = 2, ram = 4*GB, disk = 8*GB, gpu = 1),`

Just keep in mind that this is in artificial resource for Mesos, so Mesos will not take care of resource isolation in this case. For example if you have several GPUs on one system, your code would have to manage the isolation/scheduling between the different GPUs.

Comment: That's how I would guess the API should be extended,  but checking out the current codebase shows that the current API does not accept any other resource types.[link](https://github.com/apache/aurora/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/aurora/scheduler/configuration/Resources.java)